# asp.net contact page works locally but not through server

Tags: c#, asp.net, contact-form

I have a windows server for c# and asp.net pages.

I have a generic contact form on my website that will allow users to enter their name, e-mail address and comments.

The problem is, it only works locally. when I upload the files to my server, it does not?

Doe anyone know why?

This is my contactform.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();

        mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(YourEmail.Text);

        mailMsg.To.Add("email@gmail.com");

        mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        mailMsg.Subject = "Customised Order!";

        mailMsg.Body = "Contact Details" + "<b>Name:</b>" + YourName.Text + " <br/> <b>Email - address :</b>" + YourEmail.Text + "<br/> <b>Comments :</b>" + Comments.Text;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

        mailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "mypassword");

        smtp.Timeout = 25000;

        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        smtp.Send(mailMsg);

        DisplayMessage.Text = "Thank you. Your contact details and feed back has been submitted.";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        DisplayMessage.Text = "Error: Did not send";
    }
```

Comment: Change `catch (Exception)` to `catch (Exception e)` and log `e` which will contain information on the source of failure...  Edit you post with information on exception captured...

Comment: Cannot add e because it would give a different meaning to e which is already used in this scope?

Comment: check the firewall rule on your server for port 587

Comment: @user2903379 D'oh! Didn't notice it... doesn't have to be called `e`; call it `ex` or anything else.  The point is that information about the failure is in the exception which you're not examining...

Comment: no technical error came around. It just thew my error message "did not send"

Comment: you were probably blocked by the web host or by your own server.  Check your antivirus logs, and you can also log the exception's message and/or inner exception message.  Those will give you more information than your own static text.

Comment: OMG, the exception isn't going to tap you on the shoulder, you have to do something with it. `catch( Exception ex ) { DisplayMessage.Text = ex.ToString(); }`

Comment: Craig, you're right. I had a brain fart.

The error message says System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

(some other stuff)...
The action that failed was: Demand The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer

Comment: a few people have mentioned the server's firewall or being blocked by the server. Does anyone know what to do for this? My website is hosted on Godaddy. Ive tried tooking for setting but I cant find anything related